# login trouble Wordpress can change IDs created by hoster site

Tags: login

I have a big login trouble.

In fact, I created a website via a hoster site that installed me Wordpress automatically. I had a login and password via the hoster. Without realizing I am connected to wordpress by a former identifiant (a blog that was lying still and that I not use) and I changed this former identifiant giving it the new ID  that the site hoster gave me .

Firstly how that it has happened, it should not.

Second, and when I deleted the account created directly via wordpress, I asked Wordpress to send me my password but they told me that ID was not created by wordpress thus they can not  initialize my password ??? what would I do?

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the hosting company you're using you could access the database and modify the table for users.  I've used phpMyAdmin to do this in the past but that would depend on if your hosting company allows you to use this.

If you have access with phpMyAdmin go to `wp_users`:

[image]

Make sure your tab is in browse and click edit:

[image]

Enter your new password and click `Go`.

In regards to a wrong install you should consult with your hosting company.  If you dont have access to the database then I dont know what you can do except contact the hosting company.

Comment: I did not tested it yet, i'll feedback you , anyway thnx

Comment: @AtmaneELBOUACHRI if an answer helps you please make sure to vote up, if an answer in fact answers your question please make sure to click the checkmark to accept the answer.  If you further assistance please make an edit to your question.

Comment: I hav'nt enough reputation on Wordpress I can't vote up